# How to get a formatted date as a Property in the WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Im trying to format the date in payload using wso2 ESB 4.9.0.I can format the **system dat**e using below method.

```
<property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_DATE','MM-dd-yyyy')"
name="uri.var.TransactionDate" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```

but i need is format **property** value as per below but its not format properly.

```
<property expression="get-property('uri.var.TransactionDate','MM-dd-yyyy')"
                name="TransactionDate" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formatting like that only works with the SYSTEM_DATE property.
If you want to format your own property you will have to do it using other techniques.
There are several date-format functions available in XSLT[1] for example.
But while not as pretty, if your incoming Transaction date is always the same length you could also use a concatenation of substrings[2][3]. For example assuming your uri.var.TransActionDate is yyyyMMdd and you want to format to MM-dd-yyyy:

`<property expression="concat(substring($ctx:uri.var.TransActionDate, 5, 2), '-', substring($ctx:uri.var.TransActionDate, 7, 2), '-', substring($ctx:uri.var.TransActionDate, 1, 4))" name="TransactionDate"/>`

Hope this puts you on the right track!

[1] https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xslt-2nd-edition/9780596527211/ch04s05.html
[2]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring
[3]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/concat

Comment: Thanks will check this out

Comment: hi is there any way to format time using property expression
 "12:17:01 am" .and it should not XSLT transformation.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. In case of time you can use the same method depending on your incoming data. Substring the correct parts and concat am or pm at the end. Or get the current time via the SYSTEM_DATE property [1] 

[1]http://blog.genysoft.com/wso2-how-to-get-a-formatted-system-date-as-a-property-in-the-wso2-esb 

If you have more questions regarding this I recommend creating a new question :)